# CefGlue silent printing to PDF

Tags: javascript, c#, pdf-generation, chromium-embedded, cefglue

I have latests CefGlue version (3.2272.2035)

I need to save current page as PDF. I'd like to interact with my CEF somehow (JS/C#) and make it create PDF for me.

1. I've tried to use javascript.window.print() for that purpose with no success, because, all i've got is such window.

[image]

2. I've found OnPrintJob method in CefPrintHandler but I don't know what is the right way to call it + comments say: "Implement this interface to handle printing on Linux"
   and I need to handle printing to pdf on Windows environments (both x64/x86)

Any code example would be appreciated. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: [There is a patch](https://code.google.com/p/chromiumembedded/issues/detail?id=1478) that enables printing to PDF, but it's not in current CEF trunk (so neither in CefGlue). You'll have to recompile both to use that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need to merge [this patch](https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/issue/1478) and recompile cef from source; Besides, you might have to add some glue logic to CefGlue. I tested the patch myself (on C++ API) and it worked fine.

EDITED: the patch [will be merged](http://magpcss.org/ceforum/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=13041&p=26126#p26118) in trunk.

If you only need to print some pages (specially if these pages are under your control), you will do just fine. However if you need (as I did at the time) to print almost anything, you'll probably face the fact that some web pages don't render anything useful to the print view. Also, even those well-behaved diverge significantly from what you see on the screen - and that's not a CEF behavior, as even google chrome showed the same issues. In my application this was a no-go so I dropped printing and started capturing the screen (and implemented saving that to a pdf using a pdf library in C++), but perhaps your application isn't as demanding as mine was. Cheers!

Comment: I have no experience in coding using C++, so it will be non trivial for me to recompile sources and add logic to CefGlue. For now we're using [SelectPdf](http://selectpdf.com/) library to generate pdf from HTML. It is simple, free, and performs everything we need for now.

Comment: I'll ask on cef forum for the patch to be merged. As cef maintainer was aware of the patch, I do believe he'll see no problems merging in trunk. At least this way this feature will end up being available in the future.

Comment: The maintainer confirmed it'll eventually be merged.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I Hope it will be in CefGlue soon!